# How can change the state of my link on click only if it’s not active already?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, sidebar

I have a sidebar with 2 links. I want when I press each one of them to get the active class so I can change the style of the active link, for example the Color of the text becomes blue, but my problem is that if I already am at the the first link and I click it again the state changes and so my style changes again without me changing the page. So if I am at the first link for example and I press it again, the active state goes on the second link while I still stay on the page of the first link.

Here is my code cause I can’t explain it really good :

```
const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

const setSideBar = () => setActive(!active);

return (
<Box className='menuWrapper'>

<Link to={PageRoutes.CHAPTER_ONE}>
<Box sx={{ display: 'flex' }}>
<Box
></Box>
<Box
onClick={setSideBar}
className={active ? 'menuItem' : ' menuItem active'}
>
<Box marginLeft='12px'>
<SideBarLineSvg />
</Box>
<span>CHAPTER ONE</span>
<h3>Control Programme</h3>
</Box>
</Box>
</Link>
<Link to={PageRoutes.CHAPTER_TWO}>
<Box sx={{ display: 'flex' }}>
<Box
></Box>
<Box
onClick={setSideBar}
className={active ? ' menuItem active' : 'menuItem'}
>
<Box marginLeft='12px'>
<SideBarLineSvg />
</Box>

<span>CHAPTER TWO</span>
<h3>National Programme</h3>
</Box>
</Box>
</Link>
</Box>
);
};

export default Menu;
```

In tried with if statement, but I guess I do something wrong because it doesn’t work at all when I add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
    
    const setSideBar = (key) => {
    if(active && key===1){
    setActive(!active);
    }
    if(!active && key===2)
    setActive(!active);
    }
    }
    
    return (
    <Box className='menuWrapper'>
    
    <Link to={PageRoutes.CHAPTER_ONE}>
    <Box sx={{ display: 'flex' }}>
    <Box
    ></Box>
    <Box
    onClick={()=>setSideBar(1)}
    className={active ? 'menuItem' : ' menuItem active'}
    >
    <Box marginLeft='12px'>
    <SideBarLineSvg />
    </Box>
    <span>CHAPTER ONE</span>
    <h3>Control Programme</h3>
    </Box>
    </Box>
    </Link>
    <Link to={PageRoutes.CHAPTER_TWO}>
    <Box sx={{ display: 'flex' }}>
    <Box
    ></Box>
    <Box
    onClick={()=>setSideBar(2)}
    className={active ? ' menuItem active' : 'menuItem'}
    >
    <Box marginLeft='12px'>
    <SideBarLineSvg />
    </Box>
    
    <span>CHAPTER TWO</span>
    <h3>National Programme</h3>
    </Box>
    </Box>
    </Link>
    </Box>
    );
    };
    
    export default Menu;
```

send key value on onClickFn and do a execution as per key

Comment: Oh thank you so much for your help! This worked for me and I also learned something new !